# HTML in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview

I have created HTML code that creates a layout for information that my iPhone app gathers from the user. I would like to be able to take the html string and place the right values in the right location, but cannot think of a good way to accomplish this.

Example.

```
<html>
   <body>Name:</body>
</html>
```

And I am wanting to put "Eric" after "Name:".

Because my html file is much larger than this I am just trying to think of the most efficient way to basically add NSStrings into my long html NSString...

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do: `NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>Name: %@</body></html>", @"Eric"];`

Comment: I actually used this in a sense by adding "%@" to all the blank places in my html document. After fetching the html and converting it to string, I think use stringWithFormat to place all the write NSStrings in the form.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

While unknown about it's efficiency, you can use UIWebview's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to execute javascript to replace values inside your HTML page using javascript.

There are two ways to do this:

1. Dynamically create the javascript method, then invoke it
2. Invoke a statically created javascript method that is already part of your html file.

You should be able to invoke jQuery, in which case it would be painfully easy to modify the dom.

Check out this link for an example of js injection.

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview